# c++ Map [] operator not found

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, operator-keyword

```
void Library::addKeywordsForItem(const Item* const item, int nKeywords, ...)
{
    // the code in this function demonstrates how to handle a vararg in C++

    va_list     keywords;
    char        *keyword;

    va_start(keywords, nKeywords);
    for (int i = 0; i < nKeywords; i++)
    {
        keyword = va_arg(keywords, char*);
        ((Item*)const_cast<Item*>(item))->addKeyword(string(keyword)); 

        ItemSet* itemSet = keywordItems[string(keyword)];
        if (itemSet == NULL)
        {
            itemSet = new ItemSet();
            keywordItems[keyword] = itemSet;
        }
        bool isNull = (itemSet == NULL) ? true : false;
        itemSet->insert(((Item*)const_cast<Item*>(item)));
    }
    va_end(keywords);
}

const ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword) const
{
    return keywordItems[((string)const_cast<string&>(keyword))];
}
```

In the above code, first method work as expected. Second method doesn't, and shows an error @ "["

> no operator "[]" matches these operands operand types are: const
>   StringToItemSetMap [ std::string ]

StringToItemSetMap is just a typedef of map. I have tried different casts, as well as create a local string variable, but not luck. Even something like keywordItems[string("test")]; doesn't work in second method but works in first one. Is there something that I might have missed?

Edit:

```
const ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword) const
{
    std::map<std::string, ItemSet*>::const_iterator it = keywordItems.find(keyword);
    if (it != keywordItems.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

As was pointed out in out of the answers, the problem was because of second method being const while map::operator[] is not.

Comment: Have you tried just `keywordItems["test"]`?

Comment: Should i ask why you're doing a `const_cast`, and then immediately C-style casting to a `string`...?

Comment: Don't use `char*` as a map key.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, and in the result I get same error. cHao Actually it's something I tried when I was running out of ideas. As I already mentioned I tried putting string("test") and get same error. Luchian Grigore I was actually using it at first, but switched to string as key. Didnt help to resolve the error.

Comment: It's always helpful to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to prevent missing helpful code (e.g. the definition of `keywordItems`) and to allow us to easily play around to see what works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the overridden `operator[]`, which must have non-const access to the underlying map, as it will add a new entry if one doesn't exist at the requested key location. In your case that will add a NULL pointer (not going into the reasons for why).Your member function is declared as `const`, and therefore the map is not modifiable.

Either declare the map as `mutable` (NOT recommended), or use an iterator-search and return NULL if the search returned `keywordItems.end()`. Otherwise, return the iterator's object (in `it->second`).

**Example**

```
const ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword) const
{
    std::map<std::string, ItemSet*>::const_iterator it =  keywordItems.find(keyword);
    if (it != keywordItems.cend())
       return it->second;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Note: I would *strongly* advise using either direct objects, or at least smart pointers (such as `std::shared_ptr<ItemSet>`) for your map object content. [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization): Its whats for dinner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the regional post with working code. I noticed that you have a dynamic cast to const ItemSet*. I am not sure why it is needed there. Could you maybe explain briefly?

Comment: Or use `.at()`, which can be `const`; need C++11 support though.

Comment: @jM2.me I don't know what your map is holding. It is is `ItemSet*` then it isn't needed. If it is some base-class pointer type, then you should properly cast it to the right return type. This is C++. avoid using C-style casting as a practice. I pulled it on the assumption your map is as-shown in the iterator decl in my example. Hope it is right.